# Storing inputed numerical values with a for loop on JavaScript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, calculation

I am new to JavaScript and am trying to program this code for my school. The ultimate goal is to make a final grade calculator where the students input their current grades and the program outputs what they need to score on the final to keep a certain percentage. This program is supposed to be for weighted classes in which the teachers weight different assignments/tests different amounts. The problem is that some teachers use more categories than others which is why there is a for loop. With the following, the user is able to input all the info but I cannot store the extra category weights and grades as a variable so I cant do the math with them. If that made any sense, I would appreciate if you knew how to store the values that are inputed within the for loops.

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function addFields() {
            // Number of inputs to create
            var number = document.getElementById("category_weight").value;
            // Container <div> where dynamic content will be placed
            var container = document.getElementById("container");
            // Clear previous contents of the container
            while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
                 container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
            }
            for (i = 0; i < number; i++){
                // create a row element to contain each pair
                var row = document.createElement("div");
                row.id = 'row' + i

                row.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Category " + (i+1) + " weight: "));
                var weight_input = document.createElement("input");
                weight_input.type = "number";
                weight_input.name = "weight";
                row.appendChild(weight_input);

                row.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Category " + (i+1) + " percentage: "));
                var percentage_input = document.createElement("input");
                percentage_input.type = "number";
                percentage_input.name = "percentage";
                row.appendChild(percentage_input);

                // append inputs to row instead of container, then append each row to container
                container.appendChild(row);
            }
        }
        function weighted() {

            var container = document.getElementById("container");
            var rows = container.children;
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
               var row = rows[i];
               var weight = row.children[0].value;  // or row.querySelectorAll('[name=weight]').value;
               var percentage = row.children[1].value;
               console.log(weight, percentage);
             }


        // not important for now - will do the calculations here
        // var E = "";
        //
        // var A = parseFloat(document.getElementById("goal_grade").value);
        // var B = parseFloat(document.getElementById("exam_weight").value);
        //
        //
        // var E = A + B;
        //
        // if ( E <= 0) {
        //   E = 0;
        // }
        //
        //
        // document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = E;
        // document.getElementById("totpoints").innerHTML = B;
        }
    </script>
 </head

 <body>
    <span>What final percentage in the class are you trying to reach or stay above?</span>
    <input type="number" id="goal_grade" name="goal_grade" />

    <br>
    <br>

    <span>What percent is the final exam weighted?</span>
    <input type="number" id="exam_weight" name="exam_weight" />

    <br>
    <br>

    <span>How many extra weighted categories are there?</span>
    <input type="number" id="category_weight" name="category_weight" value=""> <br />
    <button type="button" onclick="addFields()">Submit </button>
    <div id="container"></div>

    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="weighted()" />

    <br>
    <br>

    <span>You will need to get <p id="result" name="r1"> </p> points out of the ... <p id="totpoints" name="tot_points"> </p> points possible on the final"
</span>

</body>

 </html>
```

Comment: To store a list of similar items, especially where the number of items can vary, [use arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use array in javascript. I have used array and your page is working fine now. 
You can check it and Tell if there some problem...

```
    <html>

<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var w = [];
        var p = [];
        var result = 0;
        function addFields() {
            // Number of inputs to create
            var number = document.getElementById("category_weight").value;
            // Container <div> where dynamic content will be placed
            var container = document.getElementById("container");
            // Clear previous contents of the container
            while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
                 container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
            }
            for (i = 0; i < number; i++){
                // create a row element to contain each pair
                var row = document.createElement("div");
                row.id = 'row' + i

                row.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Category " + (i+1) + " weight: "));
                var weight_input = document.createElement("input");
                weight_input.type = "number";
                weight_input.name = "weight";
                row.appendChild(weight_input);

                row.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Category " + (i+1) + " percentage: "));
                var percentage_input = document.createElement("input");
                percentage_input.type = "number";
                percentage_input.name = "percentage";
                row.appendChild(percentage_input);

                // append inputs to row instead of container, then append each row to container
                container.appendChild(row);
            }
        }
        function weighted() {

            var container = document.getElementById("container");
            var rows = container.children;
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
               var row = rows[i];
               w[i] = row.children[0].value;  // or row.querySelectorAll('[name=weight]').value;
               p[i] = row.children[1].value;

             }

             for(var i =0; i < rows.length; i++){
               // You can do as much calculation here with w[i] & p[i]
                 result += w[i]*p[i];
             }
             console.log(result);

        // not important for now - will do the calculations here
        // var E = "";
        //
        // var A = parseFloat(document.getElementById("goal_grade").value);
        // var B = parseFloat(document.getElementById("exam_weight").value);
        //
        //
        // var E = A + B;
        //
        // if ( E <= 0) {
        //   E = 0;
        // }
        //
        //
        // document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = E;
        // document.getElementById("totpoints").innerHTML = B;
        }
    </script>
 </head

 <body>
    <span>What final percentage in the class are you trying to reach or stay above?</span>
    <input type="number" id="goal_grade" name="goal_grade" />

    <br>
    <br>

    <span>What percent is the final exam weighted?</span>
    <input type="number" id="exam_weight" name="exam_weight" />

    <br>
    <br>

    <span>How many extra weighted categories are there?</span>
    <input type="number" id="category_weight" name="category_weight" value=""> <br />
    <button type="button" onclick="addFields()">Submit </button>
    <div id="container"></div>

    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="weighted()" />

    <br>
    <br>

    <span>You will need to get <p id="result" name="r1"> </p> points out of the ... <p id="totpoints" name="tot_points"> </p> points possible on the final"
</span>

</body>

 </html>
```

I hope this will solve your problem :)

Comment: Thank you!! That definitely solved the problem of storing the values! The only problem is that because some classes have more categories, I dont know how many values to store. For example, when I run the following math within the weighted() function, I only get a result if the user inputs that exact number of category values:                        
            var A = w[0]*p[0];
     var B = w[1]*p[1];
     var C = w[2]*p[2];
     var D = w[3]*p[3];

     var E = A + B + C;

        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = E;

Comment: Ok, If I'm understand you correctly. You want to save all weigth* percentage in some variables and finally add all variables in a single variable???

Comment: Well that was just a basic example calculation to test the code. The actual calculation is a little more complex. It will basically be a bunch of addition/subtraction/multiplication/division between the weighted (w[i]), percentage(p[i]), exam_weight, and goal_grade.

Comment: Ok, I have changed my code. You can do whatever calculations you want in the for loop with w[i] & p[i]. I have done your example in this code.

Comment: Great! I think I will be able to work with this and finish my project. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Didn't quite understand where your problem is. You can store all of your extra weighted categories inside of an array.

for example:

```
var categories = [];
categories.push(value);
```

For your issue, value can be a weighted category (weight + percentage).
Your code should be as follows:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function addFields() {
            // Number of inputs to create
            var number = document.getElementById("category_weight").value;
            // Container <div> where dynamic content will be placed
            var container = document.getElementById("container");
            // Clear previous contents of the container
            while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
                 container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
            }
            for (i = 0; i < number; i++){
                // create a row element to contain each pair
                var row = document.createElement("div");
                row.id = 'row' + i

                row.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Category " + (i+1) + " weight: "));
                var weight_input = document.createElement("input");
                weight_input.type = "number";
                weight_input.name = "weight";
                row.appendChild(weight_input);

                row.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Category " + (i+1) + " percentage: "));
                var percentage_input = document.createElement("input");
                percentage_input.type = "number";
                percentage_input.name = "percentage";
                row.appendChild(percentage_input);

                // append inputs to row instead of container, then append each row to container
                container.appendChild(row);
            }
        }
        function weighted() {

            var container = document.getElementById("container");
            var rows = container.children;
            // The categories array initialization
            var categories = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
               var row = rows[i];
               var weight = row.children[0].value;  // or row.querySelectorAll('[name=weight]').value;
               var percentage = row.children[1].value;
               // Pushing a specific category that contains weight and percentage (Defined by a JSON struction)
               categories.push({
                    weight: weight,
                    percentage: percentage
               });
               console.log(weight, percentage);
             }


        // not important for now - will do the calculations here
        // var E = "";
        //
        // var A = parseFloat(document.getElementById("goal_grade").value);
        // var B = parseFloat(document.getElementById("exam_weight").value);
        //
        //
        // var E = A + B;
        //
        // if ( E <= 0) {
        //   E = 0;
        // }
        //
        //
        // document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = E;
        // document.getElementById("totpoints").innerHTML = B;
        }
    </script>
 </head

 <body>
    <span>What final percentage in the class are you trying to reach or stay above?</span>
    <input type="number" id="goal_grade" name="goal_grade" />

    <br>
    <br>

    <span>What percent is the final exam weighted?</span>
    <input type="number" id="exam_weight" name="exam_weight" />

    <br>
    <br>

    <span>How many extra weighted categories are there?</span>
    <input type="number" id="category_weight" name="category_weight" value=""> <br />
    <button type="button" onclick="addFields()">Submit </button>
    <div id="container"></div>

    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="weighted()" />

    <br>
    <br>

    <span>You will need to get <p id="result" name="r1"> </p> points out of the ... <p id="totpoints" name="tot_points"> </p> points possible on the final"
</span>

</body>

</html>
```

Later on your calculations, your can for loop on the categories array and calculate by the categories that you've pushed into the array